# How to insert a new row into NSMutableArray?

Tags: core-data, ios5, nsmutablearray, xcode4.2

I have an NSMutableArray to has the "many" side of a one-to-many relationship.  I have it loaded into a UITableView.  When I edit the table, by tapping "edit" I have the ability to add a new row to the table, which means add a new row to the NSMutableArray.  The table Segue's to a new UITableView to allow the data to be entered.  I want to be able to save the data into the NSMutableArray.  What is the best way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

To add objects to an NSMutableArray:

```
NSMutableArray * testArray;
testArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
[testArray addObject:@"one"];
[testArray addObject:@"three"];
[testArray insertObject:@"two" atIndex:1];
```